# how to hide all blocks with javasctipt

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 blocks, one by one they appear(4 blocks), except last (block #5), and I don't understand why the last don't want. When all blocks are shown the hide and everything starts again. I would appreciate if you explain me why it happen.

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').addClass('hidden');
  var i = setInterval(showBlock, 1000);

  function showBlock() {
    var x = $("div.hidden:first").removeClass("hidden");
    if ($("div.hidden").length === 0) {
      $('div').addClass('hidden');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

Comment: it looks ok to me

Comment: looks ok to me too

Comment: Well it works fine for me

Comment: it looks ok to me too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you well. I understand that it works well untill 4th block is spawned, then 5th block doesn't spawn but all desapear? If so, then the problem is in your "code" order.

1st you remove class "hidden" class from "div"

```
 var x = $("div.hidden:first").removeClass("hidden");
```

then in the same iteration you check if there are any "hidden divs" if not then you make all of "div" hidden.

```
if ($("div.hidden").length === 0) {
      $('div').addClass('hidden');
    }
```

I think it should work correctly if you change the order and add return to "if"

```
if ($("div.hidden").length === 0) {
  $('div').addClass('hidden');
  return
}
var x = $("div.hidden:first").removeClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').addClass('hidden');
  var i = setInterval(showBlock, 1000);

  function showBlock() {
    var x = $("div.hidden:first").removeClass("hidden");
    if ($("div.hidden").length === 0) {
      clearInterval(i);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

Your code runs again and again because you never stop the timer you set.

Answer (score 0):

as soon as div 5 shows the function sets all divs to hidden, add a 1sec timeout like this and it will work

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('div').addClass('hidden'); }, 1000);
```